# Prove easy sum relationship

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

I want to understand the proof of how to estimate variance from the Normal distr, using the method of moments. It boils down to simple algebra.

I can't understand why
[image: book]
I tried to prove it like this
[image: paper]
but get an error in the end.

Comment: What specific step do you not understand of the proof. The first equality follows because $\sigma^2 = E(X) - E^2(X)$ which we want to set equal to its population estimator: $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2 - \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^2 - \bar{x}^2$

Comment: My confusion stems from the fact that they don't use $\Sigma [inside] outside$ which I prefer over skipping the [] and writing $\Sigma inside outside$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\sum (x_i-\bar{x})^2= \sum (x_i^2 -2x_i\bar{x} + \bar{x}^2)
\\
=\sum x_i^2 -2\bar{x}\sum x_i + n\bar{x}^2=
\sum x_i^2 -2n\bar{x}^2 + n\bar{x}^2=\sum x_i^2 -n\bar{x}^2
$$

so$$
\frac 1n\sum (x_i-\bar{x})^2=\frac 1n\sum x_i^2 -\bar{x}^2
$$